# How to perform validation for multiple fields in a single script in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, assertion

I was trying to execute below code to validate two fields last name and email and get result of both field if condition matches with if statement in JSR223 assertion in JMeter. But I am getting error for second condition (last name) only. Not for both email and last name. Can someone please help?

def responseJson = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()) 
def lastName = responseJson.data[0].last_name 
def email = responseJson.data[0].email 
if (email != 'test') { 
AssertionResult.setFailure(true) 
AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("Incorrect email value" + email) 
} 
if (lastName != 'test') { 
AssertionResult.setFailure(true) 
AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("Incorrect last name value\n" + lastName) 
}

else 
{ AssertionResult.setFailure(true) 
AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("correct value"); 
}
Below is the Json: { "per_page": 6, "total": 12, "data": [ { "last_name": "Lawson", "id": 7, "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/7-image.jpg", "first_name": "Michael", "email": "michael.lawson@reqres.in" }, { "last_name": "Ferguson", "id": 8, "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/8-image.jpg", "first_name": "Lindsay", "email": "lindsay.ferguson@reqres.in" }, { "last_name": "Funke", "id": 9, "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/9-image.jpg", "first_name": "Tobias", "email": "tobias.funke@reqres.in" }, { "last_name": "Fields", "id": 10, "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/10-image.jpg", "first_name": "Byron", "email": "byron.fields@reqres.in" }, { "last_name": "Edwards", "id": 11, "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/11-image.jpg", "first_name": "George", "email": "george.edwards@reqres.in" }, { "last_name": "Howell", "id": 12, "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/12-image.jpg", "first_name": "Rachel", "email": "rachel.howell@reqres.in" } ], "page": 2, "total_pages": 2, "support": { "text": "To keep ReqRes free, contributions towards server costs are appreciated!", "url": "https://reqres.in/#support-heading" } }

Answer (score 1):

Try amending your code as follows:

```
def responseJson = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())
def lastName = responseJson.data[0].last_name
def email = responseJson.data[0].email
if (email != 'test') {
    def subResult = new org.apache.jmeter.assertions.AssertionResult()
    subResult.setFailure(true)
    subResult.setFailureMessage("Incorrect email value" + email)
    prev.addAssertionResult(subResult)
}
if (lastName != 'test') {
    def subResult = new org.apache.jmeter.assertions.AssertionResult()
    subResult.setFailure(true)
    subResult.setFailureMessage("Incorrect last name value\n" + lastName)
    prev.addAssertionResult(subResult)
} else {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("correct value")
    prev.addAssertionResult(AssertionResult)
}

if (prev.getAssertionResults().findAll { result -> result.isFailure() }.size() > 0) {
    prev.setSuccessful(false)
}
```

in the above code `prev` stands for the **prev**ious [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class instance providing you access to all its available functions. See [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more information on this and other [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands available for the [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223).